# GCP Cloud Functions "Cannot find module 'express'" when it IS in my package.json

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a GCP cloud function from source code (a mirrored git repo). Cloud Function deploy seems to be finding my index.js properly (which contains the function handler), but fails with the `Code in file index.js can't be loaded. Cannot find module 'express'` error that many others have posted about. My package.json file definitely contains express, however:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/speech": "^2.3.1",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.5.0",
    "@sentry/node": "^5.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "googleapis": "45.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "stripe": "^7.1.0"
  },
  ...
}
```

My package.json is in the project root, and my code exposing the function itself is in `/app/index.js`. What could I be doing wrong here?

**Edit:**
I was able to reproduce this with a very simple app. The app only contains 4 files:

```
app/index.js
.gitignore
package.json
yarn.lock
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "cloud-functions-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:roballsopp/cloud-functions-test.git",
  "author": "rob <rca06d@my.fsu.edu>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}

// index.js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.get('/health', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'All good!' });
});

exports.testApp = app;
```

I pushed this to github, set up a mirrored repo in GCP, and deployed an HTTP cloud function with it. All settings for the deployment are default, except I set "Repository" to the name of my repo as shown in Cloud Source Repositories, "Function to execute" to `testApp`, and "Directory with source code" to `/app`.

Comment: Do you have instructions on how exactly we can reproduce this?  Please edit the question to list the steps (without linking offsite, please) to reproduce.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson, added steps to reproduce with a simple example

Comment: Are you sure that the modules got installed as part of deployment?

Comment: How could I verify that?

Comment: Rob, try without specifying "Directory with source code" as /app .... my thinking is that this would deploy JUST the /app downards ... the "main" entry in your package.json should be enough to identity the source to run.

Comment: Oh that was it! Ok, thats a little confusing, but thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we deploy a Cloud Function from data contained in a Git repo, we have the opportunity to specify the *directory with source code*.  It is believed that this causes the deployment of that directory (and likely subordinate directories).  In this story, where we have:

```
app
  index.js
package.json
```

and we specified the "directory with source" as `/app` then what was actually deployed did **not** include the `package.json`.  With no `package.json` there was no explicit dependencies and hence no knowledge of a dependency on `express`.

See also:

- [Deploying Cloud Functions from Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/deploying-functions-from-source-repositories)